# How to fix the deprecated legacy SnipMate parser?

Tags: plugin-snipmate

I have the Snipmate plugin in my .vimrc, but when I launch Vim, I get this error.

How can I fix it?

Here's what I currently have:

```
Bundle 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
```

Comment: FWIW, the original snipMate still works well and doesn't exhibit that issue.

Comment: @romainl how do you find/use "oroginal snipMate"?

Comment: You go to the GitHub page of the fork that you are using and you click on the "forked from" link and then you install and use it like the fork.

Comment: Was having the same problem...see below.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to .vimrc and restart vim, should fix the problem!

```
let g:snipMate = { 'snippet_version' : 1 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) If you solution solves your problem may be could you accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I suppose I was waiting to see if anyone else found this answer useful, and / or provided a better answer. Perhaps some upvotes would build confidence.

Comment: I understand. If you are still waiting then feel free to let the question open that is the purpose :-)

Comment: Yep; lacostenycoder's fix worked for me...thanks!